# How can I back up iPhone data to a server?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I would like to build an iPhone app that will back up phone data (messages, address book, etc.) to a central server.

How can I access this phone information and then upload that to a server?

Comment: Do you have any experience in programming already, especially iPhone dev? This seems like a very general, beginner-type question—although that is a rather ambitious beginning project. 

iOS has an AddressBook framework that you can use, although uploading all of that info to a server might lead to some privacy concerns. To learn more about the framework, check out this link:

http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/09/19/access-the-address-book/

Comment: Third-party have a very limited access to user data. I don't think this should be your first project.

Comment: yes, i have experience in c,c++ programming. but i am new at objective c. I have read your linked article. But it does not provide anything about uploading this contacts to a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/index.html).  You'll need a Mac running OSX and a recent version of XCode.

Happy programming.